# Songs wont display on free mp3 downloader app on lumia 500

Tags: lumia, apps, music, 7.x

I'm having issues with my downloaded music app on my Nokia Lumia 500 , It has worked well in the past but over the last few days my playlists have disappeared and now none of the songs are showing ! the songs are still there because when I go to now playing it will pick and play a random song ! Please help , this is FRUSTRATING !!!!

Comment: Which app are you talking about? Can you edit your question to include a link to its listing in the store?